# Visual Studio 2010 - search replace only text in qoutes or double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

I would like to search / replace text but only text in quotes in Visual Studio 2010 IDE, is this possible ?

For example I want to change

oldValue

in

newValue

but only if searched text is surrounded with quotes or double quotes, something like this

```
string something = "This string have oldValue"; // replace this  
int oldValue = 44; // don't replace this
```

btw. this is not limited on C# or VB.NET code, I would like to do this on other file types like for example SQL scripts etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regular expressions option in Visual Studio's find dialog.

Your "find what" would look like: `{".*}oldValue{.*"}`

This will find a double quote, followed by any characters, then your "oldValue", then followed by any characters and finally another quote.

Your "replace with" would then be: `\1newValue\2`

This will leave whatever was in front of or after the oldValue intact.

Since this regex isn't looking for values *inside* quotes, only values preceded and followed by quotes it will incorrectly work on the following: `"abc" oldvalue "123"`